# 14.10 NVIDIA driver makes internet very slow after install

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, internet, 14.10

I have Ubuntu 14.10. I was using my PC long time, when suddenly I found out one problem- it was cause of Noveau driver did not support GLSL(still doesn't). It also has very bad performance. I have NVIDIA GF119 GeForce GT 610 (ver a1) graphics card. I decided to install new driver from additional drivers (I took proprietary, tested) and- ops!- after installing it internet speed slowed about 5 times. It was pining like 5 seconds and download speed was below 2 Mbps. I basicaly have 13 ms pining, 12 Mbps dowload and 5 Mbps upload. When I changed driver back, internet began to work fast. Maybe you know why is it so and how to make it "compromise"- I want there to be NVIDIA driver AND normally working internet. Please, help me!
I have wired ethernet adapter, my router is Huawei E5172!
My NIC is Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
My kernel driver in use is  r8169(I think so it is faulty)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe your graphics card driver is at fault. It sounds more like your having a problem with your Huawei router configuration. Go to the HUAWEI.com web site and find your router set-up guide by model # and reconfigure your router for the fastest speed.I apoligize for the wrong information I gave you. You can also see this link for more information [Slow Internet on Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/232341/344333)

Comment: I can not find Huawei E5172 router in huawei.com

Comment: P.S. E5172 Is a new generation 4G router that can handle till 150 Mbps. I have a 64 Mbps package and my router has max zone(the source tower is about 200 m away from my home, I can easily see it from my home window). I use LAN connection (wire) so there should not be problems with connection. I have checked out my system, and I don't see reason for that bug. I really think so r8169 driver is faulty... Maybe someone could find solution for this...